# Read only папки в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]День добрый, пилю проект в PyCharm, и создаю различные папки в нем же. Но с недавнего времени система решила делать их read-only, надоело каждый раз через root залезать и исправлять это.
Подскажите как

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При создании файла или директории, среда операционной системы присваивает им определенные права доступа по умолчанию. Определить и установить эти права доступа можно с помощью утилиты **umask**. Просто выполните команду umask в терминале чтобы узнать текущее значение.

Umask для всех пользователей по умолчанию устанавливается в файлах /etc/.bashrc или /etc/.profile, также его можно переопределить в файлах ~/.bashrc или ~/.profile.

На свеже установленной системе umask равно 0022 (022) или 0002 (002) в зависимости от типа пользователя.

Есть удобный калькулятор значений umask https://handynotes.ru/tools/umask-kalkulyator

Чтобы узнать значение umask для конкретного процесса выполните команду с указанием PID процесса

```
grep '^Umask:' "/proc/<PID>/status"
```